# How to access BeanDefinitions for namespace elements in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Given a `ListableBeanFactory` for my application context, I can walk over `BeanDefinition`s and process bean properties in a desired way:

```
String[] beanNames = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
for (String curName : beanNames) {
   BeanDefinition bd = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(curName);
   MutablePropertyValues pvs = bd.getPropertyValues();
   ... // do anything I want with bean properties
}
```

But when it comes to namespace elements like e.g. this:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="NONE" >
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.dataLocation}"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

I can get hold of the top level definition for bean of type `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer` and its properties, but I have no access to its nested element `jdbc:script` and its property `location`. I assume this is because `jdbc:script` is not actually a bean. But is there any way to access such nested elements in namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule. The parser of the namespace element decides what to do with the XML elements it processes.

For example `jms:listener-container` creates one jms message listener container per child `jms:listener` but it does not create any bean for the root (at least with Spring 4.0)

Explaining why you need to do this might be a better way to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a bean post processor registered with my application context which is meant to intercept any resource locations specified and transform the urls in correspondence with the specifics of my runtime environment. It's working OK except for namespaces cases.